# Best way to create bulk upsert with casbah

Tags: casbah

im using BulkWriteOperation in order to insert bulk Documents ,this is my code

```
val builder: casbah.BulkWriteOperation = collection.initializeOrderedBulkOperation

for(p<-posts){

 if (p._1.\("object_id").asOpt[String].getOrElse("") != "" && p._1.\("message").asOpt[String].getOrElse("") !="")
 builder.insert(MongoDBObject("id" -> p._1.\("id").asOpt[String], "object_id" -> p._1.\("object_id").asOpt[String], "message" -> p._1.\("message").asOpt[String],"shares"->p._1.\("shares").\("count").asOpt[Long].getOrElse(0),"likes"->p._2.\("summary").\("total_count").asOpt[Long].getOrElse(0)))

}

val result = builder.execute()
```

Is there any way to create Bulk Upsert ?

thanks,

miki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the `find` operation returns a `BulkWriteRequestBuilder` which allows you to `replace`, `remove`, `update` and mark it as an `upsert` request. So to perform an upsert you can do:

```
val builder: BulkWriteOperation = collection.initializeOrderedBulkOperation
builder.find(MongoDBObject("_id" -> 1)).upsert().updateOne($set("x" -> 2))
val result = builder.execute()
```